Opacity of parameters when testing black box code
I'm currently working through Challenge 11 of the cryptopals crypto challenges. I'm implementing my solution in Python 3, and there are two functions of note:
random_encrypt(data):
    """Encrypts data under a random (unknown) key after inserting 5-10 random bytes
    before and after. Equally likely to encrypt using ECB or CBC. To be used by
    a 'detection oracle'.
    :param data: data to be encrypted.
    :type data: bytes
    :return: Encrypted data.
    :rtype: bytes"""

ECB_CBC_oracle(black_box):
    """detects which mode a black box that may be encrypting with ECB or CBC
    is using
    :param black_box: a function which encrypts data in ECB or CBC
    :type black_box: FunctionType
    :return: True if encrypting in ECB, False otherwise
    :rtype: boolean"""

I am at an impasse when it comes to testing my solution. Ideally I'd like to write something like assert <mode detected by ECB_CBC_oracle> == <mode used by random_encrypt>. The challenge specifies that the signature of the encryption function should be encryption_oracle(your-input) => [MEANINGLESS JIBBER JABBER]. How can I parameterize/return the mode (ECB or CBC) that the encryption oracle is using without also exposing it to the detection oracle?
ricpacca has provided their own solution on GitHub. A solution like theirs, having the encryption oracle return the mode of encryption used to be evaluated elsewhere, would work; especially since I know my own detection oracle wouldn't 'cheat' by using this information to evaluate the black box. However I would prefer to keep the mode of encryption entirely opaque to my detection oracle.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! The encryption mode is entirely opaque to the sample detection oracle you linked to. Only the ciphertext is sent to the oracle. The only thing I would add is a test to ensure the ~0.5 randomness of the encryption function.
